# Migrate database journal mode from DELETE to WAL

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I offer some export/import function inside my app and I now see, that this makes problems if an old export is imported inside a newer android version, because on many phones running android 9 or higher, `SQLite` databases do use `journal_mode` `WAL` instead of `DELETE` which they used on older phones.

**Infos/Obersvations:**

- I do NOT set a manual journal mode inside my app (e.g. inside the `SQLiteOpenHelper`)
- not all android 9 phones have this enabled (my S9 running PIE does still use `DELETE` mode), so restoring old backups on my phone works perfectly fine
- on phones not using the `DELETE` mode, a restored backup crashes my app because the database seems to be empty to my app - which I do not take care. f course, taking care about an empty database does not solve the issue as I need the imported data...

**Questions:**

Above leads to following 3 questions:

- how can I find out if the current phone uses `WAL` or `DELETE` by default?
- how can I find out the mode of a given `*.db` file?
- how can I change this mode for a given `*.db` file?

**What I don't want**

I don't want to disable `WAL` inside my app completely, I do prefer some migration based solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how can I find out if the current phone uses WAL or DELETE by default?

If a device uses Android 9+ then it should, if implemented correctly, default to WAL mode. However, device providers can provide custom/legacy implementations. As such you would need to check as is shown/answered below (actually using the method below there is no need to check).

The reason for the crash is probably that you aren't backing up the additional -wal and -shm files that exist when WAL mode is active.

I use the code below before actually making the backup

- obviously **DBConstants.DBNAME** is the database name
- and the database is stored in the default location (**data/data/the_package/databases/**))

:-

```
private void checkpointIfWALEnabled(Context context) {
    final String TAG = "WALCHKPNT";
    Cursor csr;
    int wal_busy = -99, wal_log = -99, wal_checkpointed = -99;
    SQLiteDatabase db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(context.getDatabasePath(DBConstants.DATABASE_NAME).getPath(),null,SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
    csr = db.rawQuery("PRAGMA journal_mode",null);
    if (csr.moveToFirst()) {
        String mode = csr.getString(0);
        //Log.d(TAG, "Mode is " + mode);
        if (mode.toLowerCase().equals("wal")) {
            csr = db.rawQuery("PRAGMA wal_checkpoint",null);
            if (csr.moveToFirst()) {
                wal_busy = csr.getInt(0);
                wal_log = csr.getInt(1);
                wal_checkpointed = csr.getInt(2);
            }
            //Log.d(TAG,"Checkpoint pre checkpointing Busy = " + String.valueOf(wal_busy) + " LOG = " + String.valueOf(wal_log) + " CHECKPOINTED = " + String.valueOf(wal_checkpointed) );
            csr = db.rawQuery("PRAGMA wal_checkpoint(TRUNCATE)",null);
            csr.getCount();
            csr = db.rawQuery("PRAGMA wal_checkpoint",null);
            if (csr.moveToFirst()) {
                wal_busy = csr.getInt(0);
                wal_log = csr.getInt(1);
                wal_checkpointed = csr.getInt(2);
            }
            //Log.d(TAG,"Checkpoint post checkpointing Busy = " + String.valueOf(wal_busy) + " LOG = " + String.valueOf(wal_log) + " CHECKPOINTED = " + String.valueOf(wal_checkpointed) );
        }
    }
    csr.close();
    db.close();
}
```

This works for either case as it effectively does away with the **-wal** and **-shm** files (empties them) by checkpointing the database. As such there is no need to copy the **-wal** and **-shm** files are there are no outstanding transactions that need to be committed. It works for either mode.

> how can I find out the mode of a given *.db file?

The line `csr = db.rawQuery("PRAGMA journal_mode",null);` is the line that interrogates the journal mode, there is also the SQLiteDatabase method [isWriteAheadLoggingEnabled](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#isWriteAheadLoggingEnabled()) that returns true or false.

In regard to :-

> how can I change this mode for a given *.db file?

If using the Android SDK then you can use the SQLiteDatabase method [enableWriteAheadLogging](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#enableWriteAheadLogging()) or [disableWriteAheadLogging](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#disableWriteAheadLogging()) or you could set it using via the [**journal_mode** pragma](https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_journal_mode), BUT noting the restrictions as to when this can be undertaken. [Write-Ahead Logging](https://www.sqlite.org/wal.html)

Comment: If I decide to disable WAL mode in all android version, all I have to do is following: 1) in my next app version I make sure my database is not yet opened so that no code is accessing the database 2) I execute the longer code block you posted above, this makes sure all changes are written to the database file 3) I open my database with my `SQLiteOpenHelper` like always and call `disableWriteAheadLogging` in it when I configure the database. This should be save for all devices and should make sure, that all devices are using the old journal mode, correct?

Comment: @prom85, yep that sounds correct.Noting that the above code assumes that the dbHelper connection has been closed (the close should commit/checkpoint anyway).

Comment: after an application restart it's closed for sure, so thanks a lot for this very useful help